# Where to initialize Connection Pooling, java tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, connection-pooling

I have read this page: http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html

The approach of Method Scope Connections seems quite good for me.
But i have one Question, when do i init the JDBCServlet class?
Every time i want a connection? Because i thought that everytime i want a connection i just call `getConnection()`...

```
public class JDBCServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private DataSource datasource;

  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    try {
      // Look up the JNDI data source only once at init time
      Context envCtx = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
      datasource = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/MyDataSource");
    }
    catch (NamingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return datasource.getConnection();
  }

  public void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException {
    Connection connection=null;
    try {
      connection = getConnection();
      ..<do JDBC work>..
    } 
    catch (SQLException sqlException) {
      sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      if (connection != null) 
        try {connection.close();} catch (SQLException e) {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDBCServlet servlet is invoked when you navigate to a link where the servlet is mapped to.

So you dont have to do anything apart apart from the mapping from URL to servlet which is done in the web.xml.

the web container then create the instance of the servlet by using init method and then call doGet.

This is a PDF for a servlet tutorial with tomcat, but the basics are the same.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets_tutorial.pdf

look at the servlet deployment section

for the DBUtil Class this is a good example.

```
public class DBUtil {

private static DataSource dataSource;

static {
    try {
        dataSource = new InitialContext().lookup("jdbc/MyDataSource");
    } catch (NamingException e) { 
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("'jdbc/MyDataSource' not found in JNDI", e);
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() {
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}
```

}

This gives your class that can be used by all servlets in your Web Application.

you wil call the DBUtil class by

```
try {
    connection = DBUtil.getConnection();
    statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id, foo, bar FROM table");
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

   //Do what you need to do. 

} finally {
    if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. The question relates to connection pooling not how a Servlet is mapped.

Comment: you actually did ask the servlet question "when do i init the JDBCServlet class" but the getConnection you can call anywhere within the servlet

Comment: its probably better to separate out the DB connection activity from the servet, as your initialising the Datasource at servlet startup which is not the best approach for a good implementation of code. create a DBUtil class to manage the connection pooling and connectivity and then the servlet to do what it is expected to do. if there is a problem with db connection when you start the web application your cod will throw errors and your servlet will not run at all.

Comment: Apologies @Gigaquad, I thought it was a given that the OP understood Serlvets and was asking a specific question about WHERE in the servlet should he init the connection. I've now re-read the question and can see the ambiguity and why you answered about Servlet mapping which is useful to the OP. Again, I'm sorry for scoring the answer down.

Comment: Ok now we are coming closer to what i wanted to ask ;-)

@Gigaquad: The DBUtil class, i can call getConnection() there to get the Connection object returned.
But this connection object has to be created first, when does this happen?
I think not every time i want to have a Connection or?

Comment: I am assuming that you already have a connection pool setup which you are accessing via jndi. This then takes the connection out of the pool for you to use, once you have closed the connection the connection is given back to the pool and available for someone else. I assume your thoughts are you dont want to make hundreds of connections, but as you already have a pool setup it will never happen, so in the DBUtils class you can get the connection from the datasource and the container will handle that for you. So retrieving the connection happens at the time you call getConnection.

Comment: I have updated my comment with an example. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Servlets are initialised by the Container which will call init as required and defined by the [web.xml](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html) configuration file.

Use the [Apache Tomcat JDBC Connection pools](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) which does the same in a standard way.

Answer (score 0):

There's many connection pooling libraries including MySQL's own. Many people use C3P0 which is very mature.

The common idea is that you define the Datasource in the server container and access the JNDI reference from your code. During the servlet init you're just looking up the datasource so this is the ideal place to do this. This will not use any connections until you actually perform an action.

See [Tomcat DBCP](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example) for a good intro and if you wish to use C3P0 [C3P0 Tomcat Configuration](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#tomcat-specific)

Comment: Mh.. that was not exactly my Question..

If i do: 
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)
ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/pooledDS");

When do i do this? Every time? Or when is this code executed? I have to call it somewhere the very first time.

Comment: @krackmoe The page you reference rightly placed the lookup in the init () method of the Servlet. When servlet is first accessed, init() will be called automatically. Therefore, in the doGet() method the datasource will be ready to called.